# Angular Broadcast is firing mutiple times

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following html

```
<div ng-controller = "ParentCtrl">
    Parent Div
    <input type="button" ng-click="getNames()" value="Get Records"></button>
    <li ng-repeat = "name in names">{{name}}</name>
    <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl">

    <li ng-repeat = "name in receivedNames">dsds{{name}}</name>
</div>
</div>
```

ParentCtrl:

```
demoApp.controller('ParentCtrl', function($scope){

    $scope.getNames = function()
    {
        $scope.names = ['John','Andrew'];
        $scope.$broadcast('UPDATE_RECORD', $scope.names);

    }
});
```

ChildCtrl:

```
demoApp.controller('ChildCtrl', function($scope)
{
    $scope.$on('UPDATE_RECORD', function (event, names)
    {
        $scope.receivedNames = names;
        alert($scope.receivedNames);
    });
});
```

When I click on the Get Record button, child controllers on listener is getting fired two times. If names array has three items it gets fired 3 times. Please help.

Comment: If names array has N items, you will have N child controllers and thus N listeners on UPDATE_RECORD...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of event register (`UPDATE_RECORD`) which you have written inside chile controller. It will be called as many number of times as ng-repeat gets called.

**Why**

You have defined child controller inside `ng-repeat` so it will get executed for each iteration and event will be registered. so when you broadcast it, it will execute all registered event.

You should move below code to parent controller.

```
$scope.$on('UPDATE_RECORD', function (event, names)
{
    $scope.receivedNames = names;
    alert($scope.receivedNames);
});
```

Comment: My bad... I had not closed the li tag.. Thanks. But what If I keep the above code in ChildCtrl?